# How to display the total number of a coloumn and the percentage of a coloumn

Tags: r, count, display, percentage, rscript

I need to display the following:

1. Number of total listings - the list is given, from that I need to find the total number
2. Percentage of listings - which are not reviewed : the list is given and the entries which are not reviewed are marked as NA.

Lastly, I need to add both these variables (number of total listings, percentage of listings) to one data frame and display.

What will be the most suitable R script code to use?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's a great idea to show what you have tried and a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a sample dataframe:

```
listings <- c("Listing_1", "Listing_2", "Listing_3", "Listing_4", "Listing_5")
reviews <- c("Good", "Very Good", "Bad", NA, "Very Bad")

df <- data.frame(listings, reviews)
```

[image]

Number of listings:

```
dim(df)[1]
```

Percentage of missing reviews:

```
sum(is.na(df["reviews"])) / dim(df)[1] * 100
```